# How to allow user to create a new field in react select

Tags: reactjs, react-select, react-hook-form

I have a form created by `react-hook-form` and I have a multi-select field, where user could select more than one field. Now, I want to allow users to add any new options if it is not in the list:

My code:

```
import { useForm, Controller } from "react-hook-form";
import { yupResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/yup";
import * as Yup from "yup";
import Select from "react-select";

export function App() {
  const schema = Yup.object({
    name: Yup.string().required().min(3).max(191).label("Collection Name"),
    marketplaces: Yup.mixed().nullable().label("Marketplaces")
  });

  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
    control
  } = useForm({
    resolver: yupResolver(schema)
  });

  const onSubmit = async (input) => {
    console.log("input", input);
  };

  const marketplace_options = [
    { label: "aut", value: 1 },
    { label: "nobis", value: 2 },
    { label: "nostrum", value: 3 },
    { label: "reprehenderit", value: 4 },
    { label: "unde", value: 5 },
    { label: "est", value: 6 },
    { label: "amet", value: 7 },
    { label: "dolores", value: 8 },
    { label: "tempora", value: 9 },
    { label: "occaecati", value: 10 },
    { label: "recusandae", value: 11 }
  ];

  const item = {
    id: 12,
    name: "test-collection",
    marketplaces: [
      {
        label: "amet",
        value: "7",
        pivot: { collection_id: 12, marketplace_id: 7 }
      },
      {
        label: "tempora",
        value: "9",
        pivot: { collection_id: 12, marketplace_id: 9 }
      }
    ]
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <input
        {...register("name")}
        placeholder="Name"
        defaultValue={item.name}
      />
      <Controller
        name="marketplaces"
        control={control}
        defaultValue={item.marketplaces}
        render={({ field }) => (
          <Select
            {...field}
            options={marketplace_options}
            isMulti
            className="form-control w-full"
          />
        )}
      />
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  );
}
```

I want to allow user to create new option, if there is not already there on the list, how could I do it.

My [sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-js-forked-sunwqb?file=/src/App.js:0-1886):

I am using `react-hook-form` and `react-select`, am totally new to react, so don't have much idea about it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use "Creatable" Component from react-select Lib

this will allow you to create options on the fly when you type the option you want.

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-js-forked-vdfr8i?file=/src/App.js